# How to get Chat history from openfire for one to one chat

Tags: android, openfire, smack

There are two users **A** and **B**.

- First is logged in and **B** is Offline.
- **A** send message to **B**.
- Now **B** is going to **online** but unable get message what **A**
  has sent to **B**.
- If **A** and **B** both logged in different devices at a time and
  both are chatting then message sending and receiving is done
  perfectly.

Help me how to get chat history for one to one chat ?

This is for send message :

```
public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
        String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
        if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(user1, user2,
                    message, "" + random.nextInt(1000), false);
            chatMessage.setMsgID();
            chatMessage.body = message;
            chatMessage.Date = CommonMethods.getCurrentDate();
            chatMessage.Time = CommonMethods.getCurrentTime();
            msg_edittext.setText("");
            chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //MainActivity activity = ((MainActivity) context);
            getmService().xmpp.sendMessage(chatMessage);
        }
    }

public void sendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage)
    {
        String body = gson.toJson(chatMessage);
        if (!chat_created)
        {
            Mychat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(
                    chatMessage.receiver + "@"
                            + "sspl163",
                    mMessageListener);
            chat_created = true;
        }

        final Message message = new Message();
        message.setBody(body);
        message.setStanzaId(chatMessage.msgid);
        message.setType(Message.Type.chat);

        try {
            if (connection.isAuthenticated())
                Mychat.sendMessage(message);
            else
                login();
        }
        catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            Log.e("xmpp.SendMessage()", "msg Not sent!-Not Connected!");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

This is for retrieving message :

```
private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener
    {

        public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {}

        @Override
        public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat, final Message message)
        {
            if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat && message.getBody() != null)
            {
                final ChatMessage chatMessage = gson.fromJson(message.getBody(), ChatMessage.class);
                processMessage(chatMessage);
            }
        }

        private void processMessage(final ChatMessage chatMessage)
        {
            chatMessage.isMine = false;
            SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String user = (shared.getString("username", ""));
            if(chatMessage.receiver.equalsIgnoreCase(user) && Chats.user2.equalsIgnoreCase(chatMessage.sender))
                Chats.chatlist.add(chatMessage);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Chats.chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is 'not getting offline message for user B' Right?

Comment: yes, B is not able to get message

Comment: Check your openfire settings as my answer.

Comment: Which part I have to check?

Comment: As per screenshot in answer.

Comment: ya I have selected the 2nd one i.e Always store

Answer (score 0):

First Check your openfire settings from web admin

From

Server -> Server Settings -> Offline Messages and check Your settings

For me Following work.

[image]

Comment: I have changed Per user Offline message storage limit is 1000 kb and select always store option but still unable to get offline messages.

Comment: first logout from all device and Check By login from any xmpp clients (spark).Offline work  or not in that.

Comment: As per your concern all messages are only monitored on spark, then how will I show it on my application

Comment: Actually I am newly use openfire and xmpp server for this application

Comment: for android i don't know code. but this configuration work for me.

Comment: for get ideas check by enable spark's debugger. see all stanza requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it some extends help for me, actually i am searching for getting offline message and show it in my application.

Comment: ya got all messages in archive in openfire, but unable to get that archive message.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864669/retrieving-offline-messages-using-asmack

Comment: Still not getting any clue to show chat history in my application. If anyone found the answer please give me hints.